GridDB is not connecting on Power BI through ODBC
I'm trying to connect Power BI to GridDB using the ODBC connector. I have configured the ODBC data source with the GridDB driver, but when I try to establish the connection in Power BI, I receive the following error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified


I Installed GridDB ODBC driver and then I configured ODBC data source like specified above:
Data Source Name: GridDB Host: localhost Port: 10001 Cluster name: test_griddb Username: admin Password: admin
Then I opened Power BI, selected Get Data -- ODBC, and chose the GridDB data source.
What could be causing this error? I have already used some other sources that I made locally in python and does not gave it. Thanks!
